# Excel time series data plot

Tags: excel, charts, time-series

I am trying to plot some time series data, but in a way that has stumped me so far. The salient part here is that each data point is associated with an open date and a closed date. I would like a time series line graph that counts the number open on a given date.

- Example:           Open -      Close
- first record:      2/10/2013 - 3/1/2013
- second record:     2/15/2013 - 3/5/2013

The graph I'm looking for would start at 0, rise to 1 on 2/10 rise again to 2 on 2/15 then drop down 1 on 3/1 and back to 0 on 3/5.

The actual dataset contains hundreds of records, so manual processing is out of the question. I'm sure there must be an easy way to do it, but I have not found it yet. Tried help and google search, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CountIfs()` function like so:

[image: CountIfs for Date parameters]

So, you specify the category labels, and then use the `COUNTIFS()` function to evaluate, for each category label, how many records are open at that time.

You can use the result of the Countifs function as the frequency for a histogram, time series, bar chart, etc.

Then, plot the data in columns E & F (or however your sheet happens to be arranged) to create the chart.

**Edit**

To include blank values in the count, modify the formula thusly:

`=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$7,"<="&E3,$C$3:$C$7,">="&E3)+COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$7,"<="&E3,$C$3:$C$7,"")`

Comment: you shouldn't skip days if you are presenting snapshots for particular days instead of aggregates for particular intervals

Comment: @deathApril The category labels I elected to use in my example were for ease of exposition, nothing more. This formula would work with any interval of category labels, 1 day, 7 days, 14 days, whatever.

Comment: @deathApril FYI I did update my screenshot per your suggestion. Cheers. :)

Comment: Ok, that helps, particularly with a histogram. I am concerned though, because the full dataset spans several years, so the sheet will be unwieldy and the graph will take some formatting. It should work though. If I understand correctly, countifs is implicitly combines the ifs by "AND". is there a way to get an "OR" clause? i.e.: countsif data is (A or B) and above start date and below finish date? The OR function won't work here because it won't accept arrays.

Comment: If this solves your immediate problem, consider "accepting" the answer or at the very least upvoting it.  Wouldn't an "OR" operator double-count some entries? I guess I don't understand why you might prefer an "OR" operator in this case.

Comment: Ok, after some experimentation, I think this is a workable solution. (If anyone is curious, I was able to get an "OR" effect by adding an extra column.)

Comment: David, to answer your question, I have to do more analysis than just counting all the open issues. I have to analyze high priority issues, which could have a priority 1 or priority 2. So that's where I would use an or statement. As I stated above, adding an additional column to the data will solve that problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have changed it back to unanswered (but up-voted) because I encountered a problem: Blank fields. If an issues is still open, then the close date is blank, and I'm not sure how to handle that situation. Any additional help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the formula like so: `=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$7,"<="&E3,$C$3:$C$7,">="&E3)+COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$7,"<="&E3,$C$3:$C$7,"")`. This should add the number of Open (but no closing date/blank closing date) to the sum, and give you the right number including the blanks.

Comment: Sorry for not comming back to mark this answered. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! Better late than never :)